# Babel React JS jQuery is not Defined

Tags: jquery, reactjs, gruntjs, jsx, babeljs

I've setup a grunt instance to process jsx files built for react to regular js although the file generates fine when I use it I get jQuery is not defined. I've gone through general cases when this error comes up and I nothing seems to work.  Its also kicking out some general

Script Tag Which Appears at the very bottom before text/javascript

">

Grunt JS File
module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt); // npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks

grunt.initConfig({
    babel: {
      options: {
        plugins: ['transform-react-jsx'],
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      },
      jsx: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: ['app.jsx'],
          dest: './', // Custom folder
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['babel']);
```

}

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0"
  }